# Trouble with simple bash script to append crontab file

Tags: bash, cron

I have a simple script that is not working as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash
CRONFILE="/tmp/temp_cron"
crontab -l > "$CRONFILE" 
grep "* * * * * /usr/local/bin/temp_cpu_gmetric.sh" /tmp/temp_cron
CRONCONT=`grep "* * * * * /usr/local/bin/temp_cpu_gmetric.sh" /tmp/temp_cron`
echo $CRONCONT
```

My crontab consists of one line, which is `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/temp_cpu_gmetric.sh` -- exactly the thing being grep'd for.  The first instance of grep returns one instance of this character string, as expected.

However, the `echo $CRONCONT` instance returns with `* * * * *` replaced by a whole bunch of stuff.  This includes the contents of the directory from which the script is run, but also many other things that I don't immediately know the location of.

If I remove `* * * * *` from my cronfile, the problem goes away, but I can't figure out why it shouldn't work with the `* * * * *` present.

Answer (score 2):

Basically one problem is that `*` is a meta-character for `grep`. If you want to search for `*` you should quote it like `\*`. To see why your pattern had worked out, see: [this comment by chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953970/trouble-with-simple-bash-script-to-append-crontab-file/10954064#comment14300026_10954064).

Or replace the `grep` command with `fgrep` (search for exact string.

The other problem is, that `*` is a meta-character for shell expansion, so you should do `echo  "${YOURVARIABLE}"`.

Comment: Thanks, but this hasn't really solved my issue. I already tried \\* and fgrep and it doesn't make a difference.  Note also that the first instance of grep works correctly.  Also, the problem is with the * in the file /tmp/temp_cron and not the * in the grep, since if I remove the * in the greps, the problem remains.  I didn't really understand your last point - can you expand it a little?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since `$CRONCOUNT` contains a string that contains asterisks, `echo $CRONCONT` first expands to `echo * * * * * /usr/loca...`, which is then executed by the shell, where it interprets the asterisks as globs. You want `echo "$CRONCONT"`, so that the expanded value of `$CRONCONT` is quoted before being used by the `echo` command.

Comment: BTW, your pattern works with `grep` because when `*` *begins* a pattern, it is treated as a literal "*", instead of as a regular expression operator (which needs to follow another character).